# SwiftUI Generic Pull to refresh view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this CustomScrollView which wraps my HomeView and if you pull down it fetches new data.
It works fine but the thing is that I want to reuse this in multiple views and I do not want to create a copy of this for each of my views.
I have tried to do this `var rootView: View` but it throws an error saying `View is not convertible to HomeView`.

So there are two thing witch should be generic. `HomeView()` and `HomeViewModel`.

Any idea how to achieve that?

```
struct CustomScrollView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var width : CGFloat
    var height : CGFloat

    let viewModel = HomeViewModel()

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, homeViewModel: viewModel)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let control = UIScrollView()
        control.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        control.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl), for: .valueChanged)

        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView())

        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        control.addSubview(childView.view)
        return control
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) { }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: CustomScrollView
        var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
        init(_ control: CustomScrollView, homeViewModel: HomeViewModel) {
            self.control = control
            self.homeViewModel = homeViewModel
        }

        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            sender.endRefreshing()
            homeViewModel.loadPackages()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is possible approach (compiled with Xcode 11.4)

Usage:

```
CustomScrollView(width: 100, height: 100, 
   viewModel: HomeViewMode()) {
      HomeView()
}
```

Generic type:

```
protocol CustomViewModel {
    func loadPackages()
}


// It is used generic ViewBuilder pattern for content 
struct CustomScrollView<Content: View, VM: CustomViewModel> : UIViewRepresentable {
    var width : CGFloat
    var height : CGFloat

    let viewModel: VM
    let content: () -> Content

    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, viewModel: VM, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let control = UIScrollView()
        control.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        control.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl), for: .valueChanged)

        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: content())

        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        control.addSubview(childView.view)
        return control
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) { }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: CustomScrollView<Content, VM>
        var viewModel: VM

        init(_ control: CustomScrollView, viewModel: VM) {
            self.control = control
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }

        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            sender.endRefreshing()
            viewModel.loadPackages()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try to call it I get this error:

`'HomeView' is not convertible to '() -> HomeView'`
`var homeView = HomeView()
    var homeViewModel = HomeViewModel()`
`CustomScrollView<HomeView, HomeViewModel>(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, viewModel: homeViewModel, content: HomeView())`

Comment: @RexhinHoxha, updated with usage example - for generics proposed commonly used SwiftUI ViewBuilder pattern. In you comment the fix should be as `content: { HomeView() })`