# Pull to refresh SwiftUI SwiftUIRefresh / Sticky Scroll View

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, refresh

I'm trying to keep my scroll view working as expected.
When I implement .pullToRefresh on my StateArrayView and the view is presented, pull to refresh works, but the scrolling feel changes.  It stops right when you lift your finger.

I've tried to add .pullToRefresh only to the List and everything works as expected EXCEPT when the StateArrayView is presented.  Pull to refresh doesn't work.

I'm at a loss, not sure what else try.  Is there a way to reset the way the Scrolling behaves for a particular view?

```
List{
    if self.controlCenter.ShowStateArray == false {                        
 if self.array == [] && self.controlCenter.selectedHeaders.count == 0 {
 
//SHOW DATA UPON IMPORTING...
 if self.controlCenter.showInitialList{
 InitialListView(array: self.array, text: self.text)
    }
 }
 
 else if self.array == [] && self.controlCenter.selectedHeaders.count != 0 {
 ModifiedListView(array: self.array, text: self.text)
   }
 }
 
 if self.controlCenter.ShowStateArray {
 
 StateArrayView(array: self.array, text: self.text) 

.pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$isShowing) {
 
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
 print("Refresh")
 self.text = ""
 self.array = []
 self.controlCenter.searchTerm = ""
 //self.controlCenter.selectedHeaders.removeAll()
 self.controlCenter.showInitialList = true
 self.controlCenter.arrayCount = self.controlCenter.initialList.count
 self.array.removeAll()
 self.array = self.controlCenter.modifiedList
 self.isShowing = false
 
      }
 
    }
  }
 
 
 }.padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
 .id(UUID())
 .pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$isShowing) {
 
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
 print("Refresh")
 self.text = ""
 self.array = []
 self.controlCenter.searchTerm = ""
 //self.controlCenter.selectedHeaders.removeAll()
 self.controlCenter.showInitialList = true
 self.controlCenter.arrayCount = self.controlCenter.initialList.count
 self.array.removeAll()
 self.array = self.controlCenter.modifiedList
 self.isShowing = false
 
 }
 
 }
```

Comment: That a question to package implementor on GitHub. As alternate you can consider solution in [SwiftUI Generic Pull to refresh view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371933/12299030)